# Confusion of ptr address after passing to a function

Tags: c, pointers

When a ptr is passed to a function, how to ensure its address is not changed? See the following cope snippet. Is it possible to make this function inline and achieve the goal?

```
void test(int *p) {
    printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);
}

int main(void) {
  int a = 10;
  int *p = &a;
  printf("%p\n", (void*)&p);
  test(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
0x7ffe53b10938
0x7ffe53b10940
```

Edit: the goal is that I want to maintain the same address in `main` and `test` when manipulating the variable `p`.

Comment: The function is printing the address of the *local* variable `p`, which is not the same as the one as in `main`. *"Is it possible to make this function inline and achieve the goal"* - what goal?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is ```inline``` going to help here?

Comment: Help what? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You probably want to print `p` directly, without the extra `&`.  Printing `&p` is printing the address of a variable that is holding the address of a.  When you call test(), you are copying the address of `a` from `main::p` to `test::p`, which are unrelated variables and are in different places.

Comment: Maybe you meant to print the address that `p` is pointing to instead of printing the address of `p`.  Try `printf("%p\n", p);` in both places.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure when passing ```p``` in ```test```, and test does not copy ```p```. That's why I was asking ```inline```. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You have to tell us why you want that.  It seems like you really care what address of a is, not p.

Comment: @PhilHuang if you want `test::p` and `main::p` to have the same address, then pass in the `p` parameter by pointer, not by value: `void test(int** p) ... test(&p);`.  Now `&p` in `main()` and `p` in `test()` will yield the same address.  But, why do you need this, exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The question is tagged C, not C++

Comment: @Kevin yes, I just noticed that. I corrected my comment

Comment: @RemyLebeau The reason behind the goal is that I want to log a region of memory space that when it's accessed - load or store, then it will print it out that particular address. Essentially monitoring that region of memory space. Let me know if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @PhilHuang not really, no. But if I'm reading this correctly, that does not require you to have the address of `main`'s original `p` variable, only the address that `p` refers to. You are trying to monitor the memory being referred to, not the memory of the pointer itself. [0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855759/65863) does a good job of demonstrating the difference between them.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks for your reply! It helps me clear my thought.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier to understand if you add more prints.

```
void test(unsigned *pFunc) {
    printf("Address of pFunc %p\n", (void*)&pFunc);
    printf("Address held by pFunc %p\n", (void*)pFunc);
    printf("Object referenced by pFunc: 0x%x\n", *pFunc);
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned a = 0x10203040;
  unsigned *pMain = &a;
  printf("Address of pMain %p\n", (void*)&pMain);
  printf("Address held by pMain %p\n", (void*)pMain);
  test(pMain);
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9a74E4nnK

Result:

```
Address of pMain 0x7fff2161ff30
Address held by pMain 0x7fff2161ff44
Address of pFunc 0x7fff2161ff38
Address held by pFunc 0x7fff2161ff44
Object referenced by pFunc: 0x10203040
```

1. `pFunc` is a variable local to function test. It has its own address and it holds the address kept in the `pMain` variable
2. `pMain` is a variable local to function main. It has its own address and it holds the address of the `a` variable.

As you see the both pointers have the same value - which is the address of the `a` variable.

If you want the `pFunc` pointer to holds the address of the `pMain` variable you need to declare it as pointer po pointer:

```
void test(unsigned **pFunc) {
    printf("Address of pFunc %p\n", (void*)&pFunc);
    printf("Address held by pFunc %p\n", (void*)pFunc);
    printf("object referenced by *pFunc %p\n", (void*)*pFunc);
    printf("Object referenced by pFunc: 0x%x\n", **pFunc);
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned a = 0x10203040;
  unsigned *pMain = &a;
  printf("Address of pMain %p\n", (void*)&pMain);
  printf("Address held by pMain %p\n", (void*)pMain);
  test(&pMain);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Address of pMain 0x7ffda335b9a8
Address held by pMain 0x7ffda335b9a4
Address of pFunc 0x7ffda335b998
Address held by pFunc 0x7ffda335b9a8
object referenced by *pFunc 0x7ffda335b9a4
Object referenced by pFunc: 0x10203040
```